# Show Single Image from database

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am adding products into database and it have 3 tables which are `products`, `product_images` and `categories`. Now i am using the join to show on front-end and back hand as well. I use one query and it work fine until there is only one image for every product in table. But now i have multiple images for single product so how can i modify my query any suggestion thanks.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id,p.product_title,p.product_price,p.product_quantity,p.status,
        pi.product_img,
        c.cat_name 
        FROM product p
        LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON pi.product_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.category_id
    ";
```

If i use this query it show multiple time product depending on how many images are there in `product_images` table. Now i want `2 different queries` one for back hand where i have to display only one image and one for front-end where i have to display all images. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To display all images using `GROUP_CONCAT`...

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id,p.product_title,p.product_price,p.product_quantity,p.status,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pi.product_img SEPARATOR ', '),
    c.cat_name 
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON pi.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.category_id
    GROUP BY p.id,p.product_title,p.product_price,p.product_quantity,p.status, c.cat_name
";
```

To display one image, you might use `MIN` or `MAX`

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id,p.product_title,p.product_price,p.product_quantity,p.status,
MIN(pi.product_img),
c.cat_name 
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON pi.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.category_id
GROUP BY p.id,p.product_title,p.product_price,p.product_quantity,p.status, c.cat_name
";
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark it as answered if you are able :)